# Text editors that can wrap text mid word

Tags: text-editor

I'm trying to take a screenshot of some minified js code so that I can print it onto something. I'm having trouble finding an editor/IDE that can wrap the text properly.

[image: What I have now]

Notice how the right side is jagged because it only wraps after a complete word.

What I'm trying to achieve
https://alpha.wallhaven.cc/wallpaper/120534

Is there a text editor/plugin that lets me wrap text mid-word like this?

Comment: "Is there a text editor that lets me ___?" Yes, Vim!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [vim](https://github.com/vim/vim). It wraps the text half way through a word by default but you can configure it to break on spaces using the `:set linebreak` command.